# variable reassignment problem in JS, braking my head trying to understand

Tags: javascript

I'm building my own custom made image slideshow, here is a code so far:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var images = new Array('Aerodynamics.jpg','ABC_news.jpg','yep.jpg');
    var currentImage = 0; 
    var newImage = 'url(images/'+images[currentImage]+')';    
    $('.inner_img').css('background-image',newImage).animate({opacity:1.0},4000,function(){
        if (currentImage != images.length-1){
            currentImage++;
        } else {
            currentImage = 0;
        };
        $(this).animate({opacity:0.0},4000);
    });
};

function interval(){
    setInterval(slideSwitch,1000);
};

interval();
```

Problem is, when interval triggers slideSwitch() function again, the variable newImage holds with the same value when it triggered for the first time. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong. I also tryed to place variables outside the function, gives me the same result.

Comment: @user698074 Rolled back the question. Please don't delete the code

Comment: @@user698074 stop editing your question please! You're removing the formatting

Answer (score 3):

thats bc `currentImage` is assigned to zero every time the function is called.

You should put `currentImage` into a greater scope and take the assignment outside of the function `slideSwitch`

```
var currentImage = 0;

function slideSwitch()
{
    //same thing, but lose the line: var currentImage = 0
}

function interval()
{
    //unchanged
}

interval();
```

Btw, the following block:

```
if (currentImage != images.length-1){
     currentImage++;
 }
else{
     currentImage = 0;
 };
```

can be simplfied to

```
currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % images.length;
```

Comment: I have a million little tricks that I do like that all the time, I just rarely see new ones.  Thank you :)

Comment: Wow, how silly me. Thanks a ton. It finally works, without slowly changing opacity to next image though, but still IT CHANGES THE IMAGES, thats what I needed, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

That's because you redeclare `var currentImage = 0;` inside the method every time you call it.

Either use jQuery's `.data()` api to store it in the related DOM element or declare it outside the method

```
var currentImage = 0; 

function slideSwitch() {
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull currentImage out of your slideSwitch function and it should work fine.  your interval is calling:

```
var currentImage = 0;
```

which right there resets it.